# Android Studio 2.3 Android Monitor dont access to /data folder

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

since Android Studio 2.3, I can´t access in Android Device Monitor in the /data Folder of my AVD,
Must i root the avd ? Or is there i way to access the folder ofer ADM without the rooting process ?

Comment: I have had problems with the Android Device Monitor's file manager with newer versions of Android Studio. Android Studio 2.4 replaces that file manager with a new one, though 2.4 is still in preview mode at the moment.